# Red G light on my cable tester

Tags: networking, cable

the G light on my cable tester lights up red, everything else green, the cables are in correct order. This cable runs from my router to the computer and I have replaced the computer end, computer does not recognize the cable. Any idea? Using UBIGear CH-178, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The "*G*" typically refers to the shield connection (labelled "*Drain Wire*" and "*Aluminium Mylar Shield*" below)... i.e: not any of the data pairs.

[image: labelled CAT6 FTP]

If you're not using CAT-6 or better with appropriate connectors and termination throughout the run, then this will not test out and will appear "*open circuit*". For CAT-5e there is no sheild, so it definately won't test out. Not having the shield connected correctly will typically be fine, unless you're looking for high speeds (2.5 Gb/s or more), large distances or are working in a noisy environment.

Given that these cheap testers come in many variants for fundamentally the same piece of equipment (varying LED colors, battery requirements, etc...), I wouldn't be at all surprised if your unit has a Red LED for the shield, and Green LEDs for the other signals.

These cheap testers can also vary in their operation - some will always light the LED on the main unit to indicate which signal is currently being tested, while others will only light the main unit's LEDs if a circuit is formed.

---

> I have replaced the computer end, computer does not recognize the cable.

In general, when checking for the signal ordering over a run with these cheap testers, only connsider the remote unit's LED sequence - the main unit will typically always show the correct order, regardless of the actual wiring.

Additionally, make sure you follow one of the standards on both ends of the cable - if you're only reterminating one end, then check what pinout the other end is using. If you're doing both ends, then T-568B is the one to go for.

[image: T-568 pinout]

---

Have you tried turning the unit on without any cable connected? How it behaves will inform you about what to expect from it during operation.